# SwiftUI - I can not change the style of Picker's text on screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a picker like this:

```
Picker(languages[currentIndex].name,selection: $currentIndex){
                    ForEach(0..<languages.count, id: \.self){index in
                        Text(languages[index].name)
                            
                    }
                }
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to style the blue 'English' text that you see on the screenshot. So far I've tried to give some styling to the Text, and the Picker itself but I could not succeed it.

The picker is meant to be in menu style, so I can not change the pickerStyle to another one (i.e. wheel). I explicitly mentioned it because when I make it like this, it works:

```
Picker(languages[currentIndex].name,selection: $currentIndex){
                    ForEach(0..<languages.count, id: \.self){index in
                        Text(languages[index].name)
                            .font(.custom("Montserrat Medium", size:16))
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

However, this is not what I'm looking for. I only need to style this blue "English" text:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use `Menu` instead of `Picker`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let languages = ["English", "German", "Spanish"]
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu {
            ForEach(0..<languages.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button {
                    currentIndex = index
                } label: {
                    Text(languages[index])
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text(languages[currentIndex])
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .bold()
        }
    }
}
```